# eslint: rxjs/no-unsafe-takeuntil issue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, eslint

I am trying to add a rule to my Angular project: `rxjs/no-unsafe-takeuntil`

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "es2016",
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
const { join } = require("path");

module.exports = {
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2019,
    project: join(__dirname, "./tsconfig.json"),
    sourceType: "module"
  },
  plugins: ["rxjs"],
  extends: [],
  rules: {
    "rxjs/no-unsafe-takeuntil": "error"
  }
};
```

eslintrc.js

I have .eslintrc.json apart from it.

I get `Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.` for list of files.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, was due to it not correctly getting the `tsconfig.json`. Would suggest checking it is in the right location.